# Use a Rule with a list

Tags: list, prolog

In Prolog, I'm consulting a list.pl file with a list

```
list([5,2,1,6,3]).
```

I can query list(X) properly with the output as:

```
1 ?- list(X).
X = [5, 2, 1, 6, 3]
```

but I'm trying to combine the query of the list with a rule.  Is this possible?  I checked the logic of the rule, and it's working properly if I declare the list within the rule query, such as:

```
reverse([5,2,1,6,3], What).
```

What I'd really like to do is call the designated list from the file to reverse to clean it up if at all possible so I don't have to continually input the list for all the queries.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `list(5,2,1,6,3)`? You really mean, `list([5,2,1,6,3])` right? To your question: `list(X), reverse(X, What).`

Answer (score 0):

You add the below rules in your pl file and then you can call the reverse predicate

```
reverse([],[]).
reverse([H|T], What):-
    reverse(T,ReverseList),
    append(ReverseList,[H], What).
```